# Is it possible to re-position text in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to reposition text with jquery ?

I'm able to change it's `font-weight` like so -

```
$('text').css('font-weight','bold');
```

but not able to find the method to change position of the same.

If so, would it work on text in a foreignObject ?

http://jsfiddle.net/6s2vw/

Comment: For ex: I would like to move the text in this example to the bottom right corner - http://jsfiddle.net/6s2vw/

Comment: First, do you know how to position it using CSS? Then, you can think of doing programmatically using JavaScript

Comment: No did know about 'css-positioning'. Do you mean something like this - http://www.tizag.com/cssT/position.php ?

Comment: Two things: 1) your example does not work for me in Firefox 19 (AFAIK no suprise). 2) Hint: maybe your example is reduced to this yellow box with text, but if not, you might archieve this with `div`s  too.

Comment: @try-catch-finally - as in, you are not able to see the SVG ? I'm on Chrome v.23 and am able to see it. 
Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @fixxxer: Your Fiddle had no configured jQuery (Mootools was choosen). It works fine and I'm surpirsed to see that svg text elements react on CSS styles. Fixed your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6s2vw/1/. Please note, that singlequotes `'` are not valid in HTML - you have to use `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, you need to set the attributes x and y of your elements.

JQuery Code:

```
$("svg").find("rect").attr('x', $(window).width() - 100);
$("svg").find("text").attr('x', $(window).width() - 100);

$("svg").find("rect").attr('y', $(window).height() - 100);
$("svg").find("text").attr('y', $(window).height() - 80);
```

Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z4wyS/

Comment: I prefer to group the attr vals `$("svg").find("rect").attr({x: $(window).width() - 100, y:$(window).height() - 100});`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to position the text on the bottom right of your yellow box. To do so, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $text = $("text");
    $block = $text.prev();
    x = $block.attr('width') - $text.width();
    y = $block.attr('height') - $text.height();
    $("text").attr('x', x);
    $("text").attr('y', y);
});
```